# Convert values of column (list of values) to column names and put 1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

Can anyone help me bit here? Stuck for a while:

Its a pandas dataframe

```py
id  values
1    ['a', 'b', 'c']
2    ['a', 'c']
3    ['b', 'c']
4    ['d']
```

From above to below table:

```
id a b c d
1  1 1 1 0
2  1 0 1 0
3  0 1 1 0
4  0 0 0 1
```

Comment: From the duplicate: `new_df = df[['id']].join(pd.get_dummies(df['values'].apply(pd.Series).stack()).groupby(level=0).sum())`

Comment: Awesomeeeeeeeeeeee Thanks man!! I am unable to upvote your answer :(( @HenryEcker